# JSch and RebexTinySftpServer: test known host function on SSH Connections

Tags: java, ssh, server, jsch

I want to test the known host function in JSch (www.jcraft.com/jsch/ the latest version)

The Test Server is listening to connections like this: 0.0.0.0:22

I connect like this (ipAdress and port are localhost and 22):

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    this.session = jsch.getSession(this.properties.getUserName(), this.properties.getIpAddress(),
        this.properties.getPortNumber());

    String hostKey = "localhost,[0.0.0.0]:22,128.0.0.1 aes256-cbc AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCCzaF8d0IGrjNqm+1wKcYIQCs8obYepgSpQCrONrR1CJ1hLh5tNTgEedsWfTvSoigjRRm/QtKV7uUIPCjBa+YrHfqmMOYxHi6yyEZd7TUS9a19tkph1A0EwnpQS7Ss88H3AGElAe56SaIW7mlQCWo86MdfejZBHtVFPaOUdtyRXeAPCLXzuVWIBgFh96OwFq80TyF1gE2d+l5NyPd4qgwhO+XeZXC2ZZ/KiuGSCftaIMmOxZfBDfLpqDm3Nr0KJtuDMI2vAYt+pWdIXpxx5LpYxQbHtsqhHv0A3zBTNqqR/TaPWhudf1ohflU2cYaXFAZu5lgLPBE0ZuCRkvTxW6Pn";
    jsch.setKnownHosts(new ByteArrayInputStream(hostKey.getBytes()));
    jsch.addIdentity(this.properties.getKeyFile());
    this.session.connect();
    this.channel = this.session.openChannel("sftp");
    this.channel.connect();
    this.channelSftp = ((ChannelSftp) this.channel);
```

Server key looks like this:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
Comment: ssh-rsa-key-20170614
Public-Lines: 6
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCCzaF8d0IGrjNqm+1wKcYIQCs8obYepgSp
QCrONrR1CJ1hLh5tNTgEedsWfTvSoigjRRm/QtKV7uUIPCjBa+YrHfqmMOYxHi6y
yEZd7TUS9a19tkph1A0EwnpQS7Ss88H3AGElAe56SaIW7mlQCWo86MdfejZBHtVF
PaOUdtyRXeAPCLXzuVWIBgFh96OwFq80TyF1gE2d+l5NyPd4qgwhO+XeZXC2ZZ/K
iuGSCftaIMmOxZfBDfLpqDm3Nr0KJtuDMI2vAYt+pWdIXpxx5LpYxQbHtsqhHv0A
3zBTNqqR/TaPWhudf1ohflU2cYaXFAZu5lgLPBE0ZuCRkvTxW6Pn
Private-Lines: 14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-MAC: a723d1fe05a806fc40b1a8db2dd67b2b9c15bc15
```

The connection to server works; only when I enable the strict host known check, I can't get it to work...

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The second token on a `known_hosts` line is the algorithm that SSH uses the (public) key for, in this case `ssh-rsa`, _not_ part of the algorithm, if there is one, used to encrypt the _private_ key, which does not go in known_hosts at all. PS localhost address is 127.0.0.1 not 128.

Comment: That was the solution thanks!